# Spring JPA : how can i get the last Page of an object when I do not know the total number of page

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get the total number of pages for my Object, so that i would be able to call the last page. This was the code i used

```
Page<Message> firstPage = defaultMessageService.getMessage(user, user2, new PageRequest(0, 6));

        paginationModel.setMessagesPage(defaultMessageService.getMessage(user, user2, new PageRequest(firstPage.getTotalPages() - 1, 6)))
                .setResponseMessage("Successful")
                .setSuccessful(true);
```

in my code i called the first page, just to get the total number of pages and subtracted the the total pages by one, to get the last page. This is resource taking as i get the list of content with the page, contents i dont intend to use. Is there a better way ? i just want the total page, size, current page

Comment: I also want to know how to do this for when I request a page that doesn't exist. For example, I'm in page 3 but I change a filter parameter and the new filtered results only go to page 2. It shouldn't return an empty page 3.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only last page then sort your data in descending order and then get the first page. is it possible to sort your data then your problem will be solved.